# MySQL : How to create triggers with IF

Tags: mysql

I would like to create a trigger in mysql  that puts the distance for a car rent in one row depending on the start city and the end city
I tried this but it doesn't work

```
`create trigger KmDriven after insert on MI__Rent
for each ROW
set new.km = new.StartCity*new.EndCity,
if StartCity=1 and EndCity=2 then update New.km=600,
elseif StartCity=1 and EndCity=3 then update New.km=400,
elseif StartCity=1 and EndCity=4 then update New.km=800,
elseif StartCity=1 and EndCity=5 then update New.km=675,
elseif StartCity=2 and EndCity=1 then update New.km=600,
elseif StartCity=2 and EndCity=3 then update New.km=550,
elseif StartCity=2 and EndCity=4 then update New.km=300,
elseif StartCity=3 and EndCity=1 then update New.km=400,
elseif StartCity=3 and EndCity=2 then update New.km=550,
elseif StartCity=3 and EndCity=4 then update New.km=500,
elseif StartCity=3 and EndCity=5 then update New.km=300,
elseif StartCity=4 and EndCity=1 then update New.km=800,
elseif StartCity=4 and EndCity=2 then update New.km=300,
elseif StartCity=4 and EndCity=3 then update New.km=500,
elseif StartCity=4 and EndCity=5 then update New.km=300,
elseif StartCity=5 and EndCity=1 then update New.km=675,
elseif StartCity=4 and EndCity=1 then update New.km=500,
elseif StartCity=4 and EndCity=1 then update New.km=300,
elseif StartCity=4 and EndCity=1 then update New.km=300,
end if,
end;`
```

Could you please tell me where this is wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Look for CASE / WHEN syntax

Comment: Look for BEGIN...END for multi-statement triggers; your if-elseif would work if it used proper syntax; and SET not UPDATE. ..or as @DanielE. hinted, `NEW.km = CASE WHEN ... THEN ... WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END;`  would work.

Comment: So you mean something like
`create trigger KmDriven after insert on MI__Rent
for each ROW
set new.km = case,
when StartCity=1 and EndCity=2 then set New.km=600,
[...]
elseStartCity=4 and EndCity=1 then set New.km=300,
end;`

Answer (score 1):

You need to create trigger for another table .
You are inserting in mi_rent and updating same row using trigger.
MySql gives error in this scenario.

Can't update table 'mi_rent' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Comment: So what would be the solution then? How could I create another trigger?